# Unable to build apk due to some dex problems

Tags: android, performance, build.gradle

Actually I was able to build apk without any problem but suddenly I'm getting the following error.Can anyone please help me to fix this error?

I've tried to follow similar questions in `SO` but those were not helpful and I'm unable to figure out where is the problem . It's been a pain in the neck to figure out the problem

**By the way the error is extremely long and I've posted the first part of the problem**

By Clicking on Toggle View I'm getting this error:

```
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
```

**Build.gradle :**

```
android {
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
}
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "community.infinity"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
aaptOptions {
    cruncherEnabled = false
}
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        ext.enableCrashlytics = false
    }
}

compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility 1.8
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
}
}

dependencies {
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'support-v13'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
})
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta5'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.adamstyrc.cookiecutter:cookie-cutter:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.allattentionhere:fabulousfilter:0.0.5'
implementation 'com.github.florent37:diagonallayout:1.0.6'
implementation 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
implementation 'com.vstechlab.easyfonts:easyfonts:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
implementation 'com.github.pwittchen:swipe:0.1.0'
implementation 'com.thesurix.gesturerecycler:gesture-recycler:1.4.0'
implementation 'com.github.iammert:MaterialIntroView:1.6.0'
implementation 'com.github.oxoooo:touch-image-view:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.github.deano2390:MaterialShowcaseView:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:1.6.0'
implementation('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.3') {
    // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
    exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
}
   implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
   implementation 'com.iceteck.silicompressorr:silicompressor:2.1'
   implementation 'com.fenchtose.nocropper:nocropper:0.2.0'
   implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
   implementation('com.google.guava:guava:23.4-android') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'support-v13'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
implementation 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'
implementation 'com.orhanobut:hawk:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.zsoltsafrany:needle:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.madrapps:pikolo:1.1.6'
implementation 'jp.wasabeef:richeditor-android:1.2.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:27.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation('com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0') {
    transitive = true
}
implementation ("com.github.bumptech.glide:recyclerview-integration:4.4.0") {
    // Excludes the support library because it's already included by Glide.
    transitive = false
}
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation "me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar"
implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.1.2'

  }


  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Error:**

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: where is `build.gradle`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya check the edited question

Comment: `com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19` is dead. Use `com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'`. Remove `implementation ("com.github.bumptech.glide:recyclerview-integration:4.4.0"`

Comment: Are you using Android Studio 3.1.x?

Comment: @MonishKamble it's 3.1 only

Comment: On the Build tab click on the **Toggle view** button to view the actual cause of error.

Comment: @MonishKamble I'm unable to find **Toggle View**

Comment: Refer https://imgur.com/a/mhZUVBe

Comment: @MonishKamble extremely thanks for your help by the way please check the edited question

Comment: Can you post the complete stacktrace?

Comment: **Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.**

Comment: @MonishKamble I'm getting the above error

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your gradle:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: You can also find this task app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug and try to run it on it own, so it might provide more info

Comment: where to find that

Comment: in Android Studio, on your right side there is a tab 'Gradle', expand it, there is sub dir app, search there

Comment: By doind that it's showing **FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org**

Answer (score 0):

you should try that your Applicattion singleton extends from MultiDexApplicattion and in OnCreate method (YourApplication.class) after super.oncrete put Multidex.install(this). Dont forget add this line in app gradle

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

for more information look

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

I really hope this resolve your problem.